# c# to split Dynamic arrays

Tags: c#, split

today I account a request like this.

I define five address parameters in one class ,but five address maybe empty or have value.

five address store one field in Database ,like this **(email1;email2;....)**

when to store DB ,i need get five textbox in page to popludate address add ":", this is ok.

then question is that ,when I get data from database and show value in five textbox in page.

if address have value ,then show page with five textbox. no data ,show empty.

So, how to parse the dynamic email list to five textbox.

```
string [] emailList = sourceEmail.split(‘；’);
    foreach(string email in emailList)
    {
    this.email0 =?
    this.email1=?
    this.email2=?
    .......
    }
```

I know this does not work, because we don't know the emailList have how many value.

I know one way can work ,but seems that it is not good.

```
string [] emailList =sourceEmail.Split(';');
if(emailList.length ==1)
{
this.email0 = emailList[0];
}
if(emailList.length==2)
{
this.email0 = emailList[0];
this.email1 = emailList[1];
}

if(emailList.length==3)
{
this.email0 = emailList[0];
this.email1 = emailList[1];
this.email2 = emailList[2];
}
```

**I don't think this is a good way.**
can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Just check the `emailList.Length` and act accordingly...

Comment: Oh, btw, `five address store one field in Database ,like this (email1;email2;....)` this is what you should not be doing. Read up on database normalization.

Comment: haha,I do a enhancement project ,not a new project ,customer's request, we try to not to modify the Database structure. if modify the DB structure . then have so many work to do.

Comment: Agree with @Leri, think of storing emails in a separate table and use a FK constraint to fetch them per whatever entity you are working against

Comment: @chengdu.jack Well, you have to choose do little work now and end up with rubbish that will need to be completely rewritten or do some more work and make project maintainable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just a loop?

```
string [] emailList = sourceEmail.Split(';');

for (int i = 0; i < emailList.Length; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            this.email0 = emailList[i];
            break;
        case 1:
            this.email1 = emailList[i];
            break;
       ....//Do it for all variables
    }
}
```

You can do it better with reflection, but that comes with its own expense.

Comment: if I use this way ,then only have one filed will be filled

Comment: @chengdu.jack Sorry, what do you mean? You'll have to finish the switch case for rest all..

Answer (score 2):

Add the TextBoxes in a List on FormLoad or somewhere else.

```
    void OnFormLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TextBox> texboxesWithEmail = new List<TextBox> { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 };
        string[] emails = new string[] { "test@test.test", "...." };
        PutEmailsInTexboxes(emails, texboxesWithEmail);
    }
    void PutEmailsInTexboxes(string[] emails, List<TextBox> textBoxes)
    {
        if (emails.Count() != textBoxes.Count) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < emails.Count(); i++)
        {
            textBoxes[i].Text = emails[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the `emails.Any()`, the `for` will take care of that.

Comment: @KingKing However, you must be sure that `texboxesWithEmail.Count >= emails.Length` otherwise you're left with `IndexOutOfRangeException`. :)

Comment: @Leri I just talked about the use of `Any()`, it is not necessary at all, the condition `i < emails.Length` of the for loop will ensure everything is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make use of the ControlCollection to identify the textboxes.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

So, you can find the control of your choice (in your case the textboxes named emailx) by using the key. Append the index of the loop to complete the key name in the loop. And you are done. And you won't have to make any changes to the existing code.

```
string[] emailList = sourceEmail.split('；');

for (int i = 0; i < emailList.Length; i++) {
    this.Controls("email" + i).Text = emailList[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main problem is that you have those five addresses as separate fields/properites in your class. This way you cannot flexibly set e.g. only three of them without either lengthy `if` blocks like you posted or resorting to reflection which is a ridiculous idea for a simple case like yours.

I'd suggest storing those emails in a `List` instead. This way you can have a collection with a flexible length and can use `for` or `while` loops easily without resorting to switches. Change your `email0`, `email`, `email2` etc. to a single `List<string> emails`. Then you can just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < emailList.Length; i++)
{
    this.emails[i] = emailList[i];
}
```

If you can't or don't want to change your class, then AstralisSomnium's or Sriram Sakthivel's solution would be good.

Comment: Your solution seems is a good way ,but here ,I cannot use array or list. after all ,thanks